# CKEditor 5 append HTML

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm building a CMS system for my website. The content of the page is editable with CKEditor. I wanted to make it possible to insert images that are already on the server, (so no file uploading with CKEditor). I tried multiple ways to do this and I've been looking for similar problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to do it like this:
First u have the ckeditor

Than underneath that you see a link which opens up a collapse with an overview of images on the server. If you click on one of the images it appears in the editor.

Sounds easy, seems difficult to make. Please help me out here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
var editor = ClassicEditor.create($("#content"),{})
  .then(editor=>{
    window.editor=editor
  })

/* content is your textarea id */
```

After that, you can use `editor` for replace html code, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("wayYouSelectImage", function() {
  editor.data.set("<img src='yourlink' />)
})
```

This code remove everything that exists in your ck and then add new html, but if you want append your new html to end of your current html, do this:

```js
document.addEventListener("wayYouSelectImage", function() {
  editor.data.set(editor.getData() + "<img src='yourlink' />)
})
```